# Can we use table name as parameter in command text in excel?

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, tablename

Can we use a table name as a parameter in excel (assuming there is a cell reference with the table name) to retrieve data? I'm encountering error message if I try to do so.

[image: connection properties]

[image: error message 1]

[image: error message 3]